# What mean $-\Delta G(|x-y|)=\delta _{y}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $G(|x-y|)=\frac{1}{3\cdot \text{Vol}(\mathbb S^2)|x-y|}$. Then it's written in my course that $$-\Delta_x G(|x-y|)=\delta _{y}.$$

Does it mean that $$\Delta _xG(|x-y|)=0$$
when $x\neq y$ and $0$ when $x=y$ ? But I know that $\delta_y$ is a distribution... but I always have difficulties to understand what it really means those distribution. Because as distribution, it looks that $$-\int_A\Delta _{y}G(|x-y|)dx=\begin{cases}1&y\in A\\ 0&y\notin A\end{cases},$$

but it doesn't really make sense... since we want to solve the equation $\Delta u=0$. I really have a lot of truble to understand what they want (btw, in the famous book PDE's of Evans, they also write this equation).

Comment: Note that the Greens' function is useful for solving inhomogenous equations like $\Delta u = f$. Then it makes a lot of sense: the laplacian of $u(x) = \int G(|x-y|) f(y){\rm d}y$  is $\Delta_x u(x) = \int \delta(x-y) f(y){\rm d}x = f(x)$,

Comment: No it does not mean that $\Delta_x |x-y| = 0$. But it means that $\Delta_x \frac{1}{|x-y|} = 0$ for all $y\not = 0$.

Comment: @Winther: It was a typo, I corrected it (I wanted to say $\Delta _x G(|x-y|)=0$, not $\Delta |x-y|=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already suspected, the equation
$$-\Delta_x G(|x-y|)=\delta_x \tag{1}$$
has to be read in a distributional sense. For this to make sense, note that the function
$$ g_x\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R, \quad y\mapsto G(|x-y|),$$
is locally integrable. So it defines the regular distribution
$$ T_x\colon C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^3) \to \Bbb R, \quad \varphi\mapsto \int_{\Bbb R^3}g_x(y)\varphi(y)dx.$$
Equation (1) is supposed to express that 
$$-\Delta_x (T_x \varphi)= \delta_x(\varphi)=\varphi(x),$$
i.e. $u(x):=T_x \varphi$ solves the Poisson equation $-\Delta u = \varphi$.

Comment: very nice answer. Thank you :)